# Source for literature yields

Tags: synthesis

I'm required to compare and justify the yields of my reactions against literature yields, but I cannot find any sources of literature yields for the reactions, or any reactions for that matter. Are there any resources with literature yields available?

The reactions are the formation of tetraphenylporphyrin and then complexing it with Cu and Zn, if relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What databases do you have access to? A Scifinder search would find literature references with no difficulty.

A Google search finds this technical report which has the synthesis of tetraphenylporphyrin and the preparation of Fe(II) and Zn(II) complexes [report here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317095242_Synthesis_Purification_and_Characterization_of_Tetraphenylporphyrin_and_its_FeIII_and_ZnII_Complexes).
The Cu(II) complex is prepared in this lab report [here](http://www.art-xy.com/2009/11/lab-report-on-synthesis-of-cuii.html). The references in these reports should help further.

The references in this JACS paper [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja00855a042) should lead you to other preps